# Check if all (hidden) elements contain a string with Minitest/Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, minitest

I have a list of elements on a page (cards with comic books) and I want to test if all elements have the title containing a string (let's say "spiderman").

```
<%= @comics.each do |comic| %>
  <div class="comic-card-text-box">
    <p class="comic-card-title"><%= comic.title %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Using **Minitest/Capybara/Rails 7**, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
test "displays search results" do
    login_as users(:user1)
    visit root_path

    fill_in "Search...", with: "spiderman"

    assert_selector ".comic-card-title" do |element|
      assert_match element, /spiderman/
    end
  end
```

And that's the failure I get:

```
expected to find visible css ".comic-card-title" but there were no matches. Also found "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

I have 2 issues there that I'm confused about.

1. I am trying to check if an element contains a substring. What if this element is hidden on the page (only by hovering it will appear)?
2. How to iterate between these elements to check if all of them have the substring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elements aren't matching either visibility or the filter proc you're passing to assert_selector (don't use `assert_match` with Capybara elements). If that's because the elements need to be hovered over then you should really just hover over them. Also `assert_selector` just validates that at least one of the elements will match, not that all of them will. From your questions I'm assuming the `comic-card-text-box` element is visible on the page (takes up some space) and that the `comic-card-title` element only becomes visible when you hover over the `comic-card-text-box` element. If that's the case then you'd want to do something like

```
cards = all('.comic-card-text-box', minimum: 1) # specifying count: <expected count> rather than minimum would be better
cards.each do |card|
  card.hover
  assert_css(card, '.comic-card-title', text: 'spiderman')
end
```

If my assumptions about what exactly you're trying to do, and your sites behavior are wrong please clarify in your question.